# Why is my perspective on body causing FF to not display correctly

Tags: css, firefox, css-transforms

I have an element (`div`) which I `position: fixed;`. This element should not influence the content flow.

But in a CSS-Theme I use, this rule

```
body {
    perspective: 800;
}
```

is applied. This causes my element to flow inside my body in Firefox. My body becomes scrollable to the right. (as if I set `position: absolute;`, but actually I'm using `position:fixed`)

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxWweY

This looks good in Chrome, so what exactly is happening in FF? Is this an expected behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because  `perspective` & `transform` both establish a containing block for fixed positioned elements (sort of like how relative positioned container does with absolutely positioned descendants). This is stated in the [Transforms Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#propdef-perspective):

For `transform`

> For elements whose layout is governed by the CSS box model, any value
>   other than none for the transform results in the creation of both a
>   stacking context and a containing block. The object acts as a
>   containing block for fixed positioned descendants.

And for `perspective`:

> The use of this property with any value other than none establishes a
>   stacking context. It also establishes a containing block (somewhat
>   similar to position: relative), just like the transform property does.

So this means `.loading-circle` is initally positioned to the top & right of the body (which by itself doesn't cause a scrollbar) but then you transform this element in the X direction by 50% (to the right) and rotate it by 45 degrees.

So when you remove perspective, this element is positioned relative to the viewport (which won't add a scrollbar if elements overflows) but when perspective is added the body becomes the new containing block and since it overflows the body scrollbar is added.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, your explanation makes sense :)